# running periodic task at server side for servlet JSP MVC website

Tags: java, servlets, scheduled-tasks

I have developed a web application using using servlet and JSP. I am not using any framework per se, instead using my own home brewed MVC framework.  I am using MySQL as a backend.

I want to do the following:

1. Clean up some data from the data base every hour
2. Generate and store statistics about data every 15 minutes in an XML file somewhere

The problem is: currently all my code runs as a result of the request received from a client.

How do I run periodic task(s) at the server side?

One solution I have right now is to creare a thread in the controller's init function.  Are there any other options?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to execute some initialization on webapp's startup. The standard Java API way to run periodic tasks would be a combination of [`Timer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html). Here's a kickoff example:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CleanDBTask(), 0, oneHourInMillis);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new StatisticsTask(), 0, oneQuartInMillis);
}
```

where the both tasks can look like:

```
public class CleanDBTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        // Implement.
    }
}
```

Using `Timer` is however not recommended in Java EE. If the task throws an exception, then the entire `Timer` thread is killed and you'd basically need to restart the whole server to get it to run again. The `Timer` is also sensitive to changes in system clock.

The newer and more robust [`java.util.concurrent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) way would be a combination of [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and just a [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Here's a kickoff example:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CleanDBTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new StatisticsTask(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    scheduler.shutdownNow();
}
```

Comment: Just want to add to BalusC's fantastic answer that `ScheduledExecutorService`'s `scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay` methods will suppress future executions if exception was encountered in a run. So remember to handle your exceptions.

`If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed.`

Answer (score 2):

you can use any schedular to schedule your process like quartz, spring scheduler

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html
 has a good support for these stuffs with any implementation.