# Database cleaning at regular intervals

Tags: database, servlets

I want to run  database cleaner whenever. I call for it or better make it run after every 10-15mins. but the problem is that I want it to run on a separate thread so that it doesn't affect other operations. 
 
 I am using servlets to process the client request.
I want the database cleaned(i.e delete expired rows-one of the column contains the expiry time) after, like I said, every 15 mins. I am using jboss server and postgresql.
How can this be done?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248971/running-periodic-task-at-server-side-for-servlet-jsp-mvc-website There are a number of different ways to implement schedulers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by home in the comment is what I wanted - Check this: [running periodic task at server side for servlet JSP MVC website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248971/running-periodic-task-at-server-side-for-servlet-jsp-mvc-website) There are a number of different ways to implement schedulers.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to this is to set up a php server and run a cronjob every 15 minutes

unix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
Windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Comment: Hm, I'd say this makes everything a lot more complex... I absolutely makes sense to implement schedulers in the application itself. Why introducing another technology?